# Radio button show and hide div in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a page in wordpress (it is built within wordpress custom page tool in admin interface).

What i want is 3 radio buttons. 2 visable 1 hidden.
The hidden one should be auto checked so it displays the correct div. (Maybe not needed when i use z-index in css?)

When a user click one of the checkboxes it should hide the another 2 divs and display the correct div (notice they are on the same place on the page).

For some reson i cant get this to work in wordpress. Or if there would be another way of doing the same way i am open for it as well.

CSS:

```
#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:405px;
    top:53px;
    width:485px;
    height:434px;
    z-index:12;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #F00;
}

#apDiv10 {
    position:absolute;
    left:405px;
    top:53px;
    width:485px;
    height:434px;
    z-index:11;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #F00;
}

#apDiv11 {
    position:absolute;
    left:405px;
    top:53px;
    width:485px;
    height:434px;
    z-index:11;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #F00;
}


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name='payway']").click(function() {

        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

HTML/PHP:

```
 <p>
      <input type="radio" name="payway" value="apDiv10"  />
      pay2

      <input type="radio" name="payway" value="apDiv3" checked="checked" style="display:none;">

  </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="payway" value="apDiv11" />
      Pay1

    </p>


<div id="apDiv3" class="desc">

This is the standard div that should be visable

</div>


<div id="apDiv10" class="desc">

Shows this div when user click on checkbox pay2

</div>


<div id="apDiv11" class="desc">

Shows when user click checkbox pay1

</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9YXNE

Comment: Seems to work. You may be getting a conflict with jQuery and whatever WP uses. Any errors in the console?

Comment: could also potentially be a CSS conflict

Comment: Also please use a common class for those elements e.g. `.apdiv` (or the existing `.desc`, as 90% of their properties overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments its not a CSS conflict but am unsure about the <script> part is it needed to be in the head? or will it work to have in the html as well (its only for this custom page i make). Seems like it wont trigger the script at all. So something is wrong with the script part and wordpress togheter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems when i looked at the head.php file there was a script that dident work which made my script not to work at all.
Once i removed the script from the head it worked.

Thank you all!